# Jenkins: Run Windows batch commands in 32-bit mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, 32bit-64bit, wow64

Using Jenkins, we have setup automation testing - install application and run test cases in a remote machine. This process is done using a batch file. As it is a windows application I have to logout (remote machine) of the system keeping the session active. For that I have used the below script:

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user testuser') do 
(C:\Windows\system32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console )
```

In remote machine, when I run this script manually, it works perfectly. But when the same script (batch file) is run from Jenkins I am getting following error:

> 'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: is your Jenkins 32 bit?

Comment: i am new to Jenkins. what are the steps to find out Jenkins version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're running `query` from a 32-bit process. On 64-bit Windows 32-bit processes will be put under [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access `%windir%\System32`, the access is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`. Access to `%windir%\lastgood\system32` is redirected to `%windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64`. Access to `%windir%\regedit.exe` is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe`

On 64-bit Windows System32 is for 64-bit system tools and SysWOW64 is for 32-bit ones. `query` is 64-bit only so it won't be available in SysWOW64 and can't be seen by 32-bit processes

```
C:\>where query
C:\Windows\System32\query.exe
```

You can check this with the 32-bit cmd in SysWOW64:

```
>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c query user testuser
'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c where query
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

You need to change `query user testuser` to `%windir%\sysnative\query.exe user testuser`. Or better [change to 64-bit Jenkins](https://blog.geo.bg/2017/11/12/64-bit-jenkins/)

Comment: This solution worked if the remote desktop machine is opened, it is locking the machine and the test scripts ran successfully. But when the remote desktop machine is not opened then the same problem i face, Automation scripts are failing again.

Comment: I'm not sure how your system is set up but it's easy to check if query.exe is in system32 or sysnative and save the path to a variable then just use that variable to run

Comment: Dude, this is awesome!  Kudos @phuclv !!