# Why is the wsl command not found by CMD on starting a batch file with a double click in FreeCommander?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, wsl-2, autostart

I want to use a batch script to start Docker in Windows Subsystem for Linux at login. It works when I run the batch file as administrator. So I followed this guide: [Always Run Batch file as Administrator in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/run-as-administrator-for-batch-files)

Then I placed the shortcut into the `Startup` folder. The script is started, but it exits always at the first line.

Then I tried to run manually the batch file in *FreeCommander*. The batch script works when I run the script as administrator via right click context menu item. But there is output an error message when I run the batch script with a double click. The output error message is:

> The command "wsl" is either misspelled or could not be found.

This is the batch script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%g IN (`wsl.exe sh -c "hostname -I"`) do (SET "ip=%%g")
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=2375 connectport=2375 connectaddress=%ip%
wsl sh -c "sudo dockerd -H tcp://%ip%"
```

I removed also once Windows Subsystem for Linux completely and reinstalled it, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Myrkjartan that's because you're using a 32-bit browser. Throw it away and use a 64-bit one instead, or for some reason you can't do that then use `C:\Windows\SysNative` which redirects to the real system32 folder: [Executable "C:\Windows\System32\Fodhelper.exe" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66262735/995714), [Jenkins: Run Windows batch commands in 32-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47697743/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executable "C:\Windows\System32\Fodhelper.exe" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262735/executable-c-windows-system32-fodhelper-exe-not-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be read first the following Microsoft documentation pages:

- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)
- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys)

There are **two** system directories on 64-bit Windows with a processor with AMD64 architecture:

1. `%SystemRoot%\System32` with 64-bit applications used by 64-bit applications by default.
2. `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` with 32-bit applications used by 32-bit applications by default.

The **system** environment variable `PATH` contains by Windows default `%SystemRoot%\System32` as first folder path. If a 32-bit application starts `cmd.exe` to process a batch file, there is started 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` because of the file system redirector.

`cmd.exe` is searching for files specified in a batch file just with file name without or with file extension and without path by using the **local** environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` as explained in full details by [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

`wsl.exe` belongs to the set of executables which on AMD64 Windows exists only as 64-bit version in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. There is no 32-bit version in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` searched by 32-bit `cmd.exe` on using `%SystemRoot%\System32` in expanded form in **local** `PATH` because of file system redirector. For that reason the batch file as posted in the question does not work on being processed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` on Windows x64.

The solution is taking WOW64 into account with additional code in the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\wsl.exe set "FileNameWSL=%SystemRoot%\System32\wsl.exe" & goto RunWSLCommands
if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\wsl.exe set "FileNameWSL=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\wsl.exe" & goto RunWSLCommands
echo ERROR: Could not find wsl.exe. Script execution aborted.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("!CMDCMDLINE!") do endlocal & if /I "%%~nG" == "cmd" if /I "%%~H" == "/c" pause
exit /B
:RunWSLCommands
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('%FileNameWSL% sh -c "hostname -I"') do set "ip=%%g"
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=2375 connectport=2375 connectaddress=%ip%
%FileNameWSL% sh -c "sudo dockerd -H tcp://%ip%"
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `netsh /?`
- `netsh interface /?`
- `netsh interface portproxy /?`
- `netsh interface portproxy add /?`
- `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`